# Error - Cannot contact site at the specified URL. There is no Web named "*.asmx"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying a read all the documents folder and subfolder from a share point website using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`.
This is the code which i am using for this:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string siteUrl = @"http://servername/sites/subfolder/default.aspx";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        FolderCollection collFolder = site.Folders;
        clientContext.Load(collFolder);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("The current site contains the following folders:\n\n");
        foreach (Folder myFolder in collFolder)
            Console.WriteLine(myFolder.Name);
        }
```

While debugging i am getting the below error on `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` code.
Error-

Cannot contact site at the specified URL `http://servername/sites/subfolder/default.aspx`. There is no Web named "`/sites/subfolder/default.aspx/_vti_bin/sites.asmx`".

Please help me to fix this as i am new to the sharepoint and already googled alot on this error but not able to fix it.

Thanks in Advance for all the Coders .

Comment: I do not have server name I have site name url like this and getting same error - https://sp.mydemosite.com/customer what could be the solution? byusing tracert i find out ipaddress for this site but still getting error- The connection was closed unexpectedly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your site path is not specified correctly.

instead of

```
string siteUrl = @"http://servername/sites/subfolder/default.aspx";
```

try

```
string siteUrl = @"http://servername/";
```

if that doesnt work, use whatever address you can enter into your browser of choice to get the site to load.

Comment: I do not have server name I have site name url like this and getting same error - `https://sp.mydemosite.com/customer` what could be the solution? byusing `tracert` i find out ipaddress for this site but still getting error- The connection was closed unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

There must be some error code statement in web.config of your application.

Try changing `SessionState mode` from `InProc` to `SQLServer`.

example:

comment this in your web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" />
```

and use something like this in your web.config as per your database

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="60" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=db;Initial Catalog=MyTestDB_j34b37c3674f46afa09chgsd278a35fa;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Connect Timeout=15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

your site is just Fba
you should enable windows authentication too.
for windows authentication go to centeral admin and select web application and .....