# Cannot contact site at the specified URL. There is no Web named "*.asmx" error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, office365

I want to get the file from the office 365 share point using user credentials (have full access)
but while executing the program at runtime I'm getting the following error.

For this error I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739437/error-cannot-contact-site-at-the-specified-url-there-is-no-web-named-asmx) but not given the proper knowledge. And I have tried as per accepted answer but not working.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException: 'Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files. There is no Web named "/sites/my_files/all Files/_vti_bin/sites.asmx"

below is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files";
            string folderpath = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task";
            string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";

            Program.DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(url, folderpath, templocation);
        }
    
static void DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(string siteUrl, string siteFolderPath, string localTempLocation)
        {
            string userName = "aaaa@xxxxxx.com";
            string pswd = "ssssss@1043";
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in pswd.ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
            var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            //ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
           

            FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(siteFolderPath).Files;

            ctx.Load(files);
            if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
            {
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //getting error here : Cannot contact site at the specified URL. There is no Web named "*.asmx"
            }

            foreach (File file in files)
            {
                FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                var filePath = localTempLocation + "\\" + file.Name;
                System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);

            }
        }
```

Suggest me how to achieve this and what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(siteFolderPath)` you pass an absolute path. `siteFolderPath` is `"https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task"`.

Change `siteFolderPath` to relative path:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files";
    // absolutePath: https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task
    string folderRelativePath = "Task";
    string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";

    Program.DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(url, folderRelativePath, templocation);
}
```

Comment: Hi @user2250152 thanks for your comment  I have used your answer and I'm getting the same kind of error  as I mentioned in the post `Cannot contact site at the specified URL. There is no Web named "*.asmx"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing, please change the site Url as `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename`.

For example: `https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/zellatest`.In your code it should be:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files";
        string folderpath = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task";
        string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";

        Program.DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(url, folderpath, templocation);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Zella_msft thanks for your comment and when I'm passing the `URL` like you mentioned `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files` I'm getting this error `Sorry, you don't have access.` can you please suggest me on this should I get access or not ?